# IDL's INT_TABULATE - SciPy equivalent?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, idl, idl-programming-language

I am working on moving some code from IDL into python.  One IDL call is to INT_TABULATE which performs integration on a fixed range.

> The INT_TABULATED function integrates a tabulated set of data { xi , fi } on the closed interval [MIN(x) , MAX(x)], using a five-point Newton-Cotes integration formula.

`Result = INT_TABULATED( X, F [, /DOUBLE] [, /SORT] )`

Where result is the area under the curve.

[IDL DOCS](http://www.physics.nyu.edu/grierlab/idl_html_help/I16.html#wp750296)

My question is, does Numpy/SciPy offer a similar form of integration?  I see that `[scipy.integrate.newton_cotes]` exists, but it appears to return "[weights and error coefficient for Newton-Cotes integration](http://docs.continuum.io/scipy/integrate.html) instead of area".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scipy does not provide such a high order integrator for tabulated data by default. The closest you have available without coding it yourself is [`scipy.integrate.simps`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.simps.htm), which uses a 3 point Newton-Cotes method.

If you simply want to get comparable integration precision, you could split your `x` and `f` arrays into 5 point chunks and integrate them one at a time, using the weights returned by `scipy.integrate.newton_cotes` doing something along the lines of:

```
def idl_tabulate(x, f, p=5) :
    def newton_cotes(x, f) :
        if x.shape[0] < 2 :
            return 0
        rn = (x.shape[0] - 1) * (x - x[0]) / (x[-1] - x[0])
        weights = scipy.integrate.newton_cotes(rn)[0]
        return (x[-1] - x[0]) / (x.shape[0] - 1) * np.dot(weights, f)
    ret = 0
    for idx in xrange(0, x.shape[0], p - 1) :
        ret += newton_cotes(x[idx:idx + p], f[idx:idx + p])
    return ret
```

This does 5-point Newton-Cotes on all intervals, except perhaps the last, where it will do a Newton-Cotes of the number of points remaining. Unfortunately, this will not give you the same results as `IDL_TABULATE` because the internal methods are different:

- Scipy calculates the weights for points not equally spaced using what seems like a least-sqaures fit, I don't fully understand what is going on, but the code is pure python, you can find it in your Scipy installation in file `scipy\integrate\quadrature.py`.
- `INT_TABULATED` always performs 5-point Newton-Cotes on equispaced data. If the data are not equispaced, it builds an equispaced grid, using a cubic spline to interpolate the values at those points. You can check the code [here](http://idlastro.gsfc.nasa.gov/ftp/ittvislib/int_tabulated.pro).

For the example in the `INT_TABULATED` docstring, which is suppossed to return `1.6271` using the original code, and have an exact solution of `1.6405`, the above function returns:

```
>>> x = np.array([0.0, 0.12, 0.22, 0.32, 0.36, 0.40, 0.44, 0.54, 0.64,
...               0.70, 0.80])
>>> f = np.array([0.200000, 1.30973, 1.30524, 1.74339, 2.07490, 2.45600,
...               2.84299, 3.50730, 3.18194, 2.36302, 0.231964])
>>> idl_tabulate(x, f)
1.641998154242472
```